# border router still showing the node that already powered off

Tags: contiki, coap

In my setup, I have couple of nodes running contiki coap server and a border router. When I turned off any nodes, that node didn't disappear from route list. Can I somehow make that node disappear from route list in 2-5 minutes after they powered off?

Comment: Also 2-5 min is a very short time for these low-power, low packet rate systems. The default timeout of a route is 30 min. In addition, there have been at least one RPL fix in Contiki-NG recently that improves the deletion of old RPL neighbors.

Comment: @kfx can you point in border router code where that default 30 minute time is?

Comment: That's defined as `RPL_DEFAULT_LIFETIME` in the source code.

Comment: Thanks @kfx, you answered my question.